# Error uploading Drupal 7 site to server

Tags: drupal, hosting, drupal-7

Hi
Ive recently finished making a website is drupal 7, with the following modules:

- CCK
- CHAOS TOOL SUITE
- Pathauto
- Token
- PANELS
- Wysiwyg
- VIEWS

It works absolutely fine on my PC and laptop both with a fresh install of WAMP server. When I upload to my hosting however I get the following error:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in
/var/www/html/rj/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1406
```

Which is:

```
function t($string, array $args = array(), array $options = array()) {
  global $language;
  static $custom_strings;

  // Merge in default.
  if (empty($options['langcode'])) {
     $options['langcode'] = isset($language->language) ? $language->language : 'en';
  }
  if (empty($options['context'])) {
  $options['context'] = '';
  }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal 7 require PHP 5.2.5 or higher. Please check what version of your PHP is running on your server. I guess it come from a PHP version less than the one requiered.

Check the **[System requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements)** page.

> Required: PHP version 4.4.0 or higher
>   for Drupal 5 and Drupal 6, PHP 5.2.5
>   or higher for Drupal 7